# Need to write code involving Jquery .hover and the Jquery .hoverIntent to work in unison?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a couple of scripts that I am looking to get to work in unison, but don't know how to go about writing the code to do just that. Problem being the Jquery .hoverIntent placed on the first li on my mega menu and a Jquery .hover event to darken the background on everything but the dropdown/hover ul are not in unison.  My main goal is getting the two scripts to work together in unison to delay firing by using .hoverIntent on accidental roll overs.

Here is my [webpage](http://www.atlantic-county.org/indexResp.asp)

//Dropdown navigation - adds background fade on hover

```
$('.nav.nav-pills.nav-justified a.dropdown-toggle, ul.dropdown-menu' ).hover(
    function () {
        $('.hover-opacity').css({"opacity": .5, "visibility": "visible"});
            }, 
               function () {
             $('.hover-opacity').css({"opacity": 0, "visibility": "hidden"});

                 });
```

//hoverIntent

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu").hoverIntent({
over: makeTall,
out: makeShort,
selector: 'li'});
```

//Bootstrap Hover Dropdown

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdownHover({hoverDelay:500, delay:500});
```

//sample of the dropdown menu code

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
     <li class="dropdown yamm-fullwidth"><a href="/news/" title="County News" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Residents&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
       <ul id="residents" class="dropdown-menu">
         <li class="yamm-content">
           <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-3">
             <h3 class="title"><a href="/news/" title="County News">All County</a></h3>
               <ul>
                 <li><a href="/county-government/county-phone-numbers.asp" title="County Phone Numbers - Hotlines">County Toll-Free Numbers</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/county-government/county-phone-numbers.asp#hotlines" title="Departments">Hotlines</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/news/" title="County News">County News</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/news/traffic-list.asp" title="Traffic Advisories">Traffic Advisories</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/calendar/index.asp" title="County Calendar">Events Calendar</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/photo-gallery/" title="Photo Gallery">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/subscriptions/" title="Online Subscription Services">Online Subscription Services</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/social-media/">Social Media</a></li>
                 <li></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           </div>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Solved another separate issue with other scripts not working on the page by combining the .hoverIntent with the .dropdownHover to this:

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu').hoverIntent(
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdownHover({delay:500})
);
```

Comment: It would help if you could sum up your question into a sentence or two. It's difficult to work through the block of text to see what it is you're asking exactly.

Comment: I rephrased my title and question, I do agree it would have been difficult to work through the old question. Hopefully this is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is JavaScript, so you can just write a JavaScript [if-else statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Answer (score 0):

My coworker came up with a solution using css transitions in the .hover event which gives it just the right amount of time delay to work in unison with the hoverIntent as follows:

```
$('.nav.nav-pills.nav-justified a.dropdown-toggle, ul.dropdown-menu' ).hover(
    function () {
$('.hover-opacity').css({"opacity": .5, "visibility": "visible"});
$('.hover-opacity').css({"transition": "opacity 0.2s .5s ease"});
            }, 
                               function () {
             $('.hover-opacity').css({"opacity": 0, "visibility": "hidden"});

     });
```

View [webpage](http://atlantic-county.org/news/)